# Debugging type errors in GHC and Haskell function application

Tags: haskell, ghci

I was solving [10th](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/1_to_10) problem from 99 problems in Haskell.

My solution was

```
-- Problem 10
encode:: String -> [(Int, Char)]
encode [] = []
encode (x:xs) = (length $ x : takeWhile (==x) xs, x) : encode $ dropWhile (==x) xs
```

The error that I got was

```
Prelude> :l 10-20.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 10-20.hs, interpreted )

10-20.hs:4:17:
    Couldn't match expected type `[Char] -> [(Int, Char)]'
                with actual type `[(Int, Char)]'
    The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
    but its type `[(Int, Char)]' has none
    In the expression:
      (length $ x : takeWhile (== x) xs, x) : encode
      $ dropWhile (== x) xs
    In an equation for `encode':
        encode (x : xs)
          = (length $ x : takeWhile (== x) xs, x) : encode
            $ dropWhile (== x) xs

10-20.hs:4:56:
    Couldn't match expected type `[(Int, Char)]'
                with actual type `String -> [(Int, Char)]'
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `encode'
    In the expression: (length $ x : takeWhile (== x) xs, x) : encode
    In the expression:
      (length $ x : takeWhile (== x) xs, x) : encode
      $ dropWhile (== x) xs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Once I changed the code to

```
-- Problem 10
encode:: String -> [(Int, Char)]
encode [] = []
encode (x:xs) = (length $ x : takeWhile (==x) xs, x) : encode (dropWhile (==x) xs)
```

It compiles and run fine. Notice I just changed `encode $ dropWhile (==x) xs` to `encode (dropWhile (==x) xs)`

I have two questions here

- How do I infer the change that I did (removing the `$` application) from the GHCi error shown? I am unable to decipher this from the error thrown
- Why does removing the `$` work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`($)` performs function application with very low precedence, so

```
(length $ x : takeWhile (==x) xs, x) : encode $ dropWhile (==x) xs
```

is equivalent to

```
((length $ x : takeWhile (==x) xs, x) : encode) (dropWhile (==x) xs)
```

Which is ill-typed for two reasons. Firstly,

```
((length $ x : takeWhile (==x) xs, x) : encode)
```

would be a list built with the outermost `(:)`, and not a function, and so it cannot be applied (thus the first error about the "first argument of `($)`" which should take one argument). Secondly, encode is a `String -> [(Int, Char)]` function, and so it can't be the second argument of the outermost `(:)` (which should be a `[(Int, Char)]` given the type of the first argument, thus the second error).

Comment: That pretty much answers both of my questions. However I am still confused about "would be a list built with the outermost (:), and not a function, and so it cannot be applied (thus the first error about the "first argument of ($)" which should take one argument).". I understand that (:) cannot take a function but how does that translate into the error of first argument of ($)

Comment: (:) can take a function. id : const 3 : asTypeOf 5 : [] is a list of numeric endofunctions, for example. @kumardevvrat

Comment: In other words, `(:)` can take a function (as its first argument), in which case it will produce a list of functions, but it can't produce a function.